Why it is a dual LP?
I am trying to understand (1) in the proof of Lemma 3 of this paper
Given a graph $G$ on vertex set $V$, let $s:V\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a weight function on the vertices. Let the weight of an edge $e=\{u,v\}$ be $\frac{s(u)+s(v)}{2}$, and let $d_s(x,y)$, the weighted distance between two vertices $x,y$, be the minimum edge weight of a path between $x$ and $y$.
Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the collection of all paths in $G$, and $\mathcal{P}_{uv}$ be the collection of all paths in $G$ between two vertices $u$ and $v$.
An all-pair unit-demand multicommodity flow in $G$ is a map $\phi:\mathcal{P}\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $\sum_{P\in\mathcal{P}_{uv}}\phi(p)=1$ for every distinct $u,v\in V$.
Let $$cong_\phi(w)=\sum_{P\in\mathcal{P}:\text{$w$ is an internal vertex of $P$}}\phi(P)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{P\in\mathcal{P}:\text{$w$ is an  endvertex of $P$}}\phi(P).$$
Let $vcong(G)=\min_\phi\max_{w\in V}cong_\phi(w)$, where the maximum is taken over all all-pair unit-demand multicommodity flows $\phi$.
The author claim that it is "easy" to derive
$$\frac{1}{vcong(G)}=\min\{ \sum_{v\in V}s(v): \sum_{\{u,v\}\in \binom{V}{2}}d_s(u,v)=1 \},$$
following Section 4 of another reference.
While to my knowledge, I can understand that the minimum is equal to
$$\max \epsilon$$ subject to $$\sum_{P\in\mathcal{P}_{uv}}\gamma(P)\ge \epsilon$$ for all $\{u,v\}\in\binom{V}{2}$ and $$cong_\gamma(w)\le 1$$ for all $w\in V$ over all $\gamma:\mathcal{P}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
I feel one needs to consider the equivalent constraint with respect to $\gamma(P)/\epsilon$. But I am still not clear why this maximum is equal to what the author claims. (And why it can restrict to those $\phi$ that mapped to $[0,1]$ and $=1$ for all pairs?)
